# Is there any way to Style Php variable with CSS?

Tags: php, html, css

Is there any way to style a Php Variable with CSS style sheet. I've following php variable:

```
if(empty($email)){
    $msg[] = "Email address required.";
    $msg['error'] = true;
}
```

I want to style this Php variable`$msg[]` to color red. Is it possible. If so how can do this ?

Yes, I can style this error message with

```
<font color='red'>....</font>
```

or using

```
<div class='error'>
```

But I've too many validation in my form so that I'm finding a way to color a Php variable.

Comment: PHP generates data that goes in the HTML, there isn't a way to style a PHP variable that doesn't use HTML because that's all PHP can do to the browser, generate HTML.

Comment: Hello everyone, I'm new in Web Development field. So that I'm asking this question to you. But I see my question is down voting :(

Comment: `<div class='error'><?=$yourvariable?></div>` ?

Comment: Don't be discouraged by down-voting--it isn't a personal attack or an indication of your popularity. It's just an assessment of your question, which does happen to be pretty poorly conceived, because it belies a fundmanetal lack of understanding of your problem domain, and you should probably be starting with a good book instead of with Stack Overflow.

Comment: @ElGavian Short-tags should be avoided, as its deprecated.

Comment: @Shibbir: Your question is being downvoted because it shows no research effort on your part. This is something that you should be able to figure out by reading a quick tutorial or doing a quick Google search. There are TONS of resources out there for beginning PHP developers. Believe it or not, people learned how to program before Stack Overflow even existed...

Comment: @ChrisMagnussen: Good point, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Filo why? Posting the entire page of code would be completely unnecessary and counter productive here.

Comment: @ElGavilan , I think that with the full code we can understand how he do the output of $msg and than we can give a better answer

Comment: @BrianWarshaw I know, I just want to see how Shibbir do the output, according to that there may be different ways to respond.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* im getting what you are asking for here;

```
// Set an array to hold all your errors
$messages = [];

// Define what inputs to validate
$fields_to_check = ['email', 'username', 'password'];

// Loop through and check for empty values
foreach($fields_to_check as $field)
{
    // Fill $messages with errors if validation failed.
    if (!isset($_POST[$field]) || empty($_POST[$field]))
    {
        $messages[$field] = ucfirst($field).' is required!';
    }
}

// If $messages is not empty, there are errors.
if (!empty($messages))
{
    $html = '<ul>';
    foreach($messages as $input => $message)
    {
        $html .= '<li class="red">'.$message.'</li>';
    }
    $html .= '</ul>';

    return $html;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The output of `$msg` will be colored red...

```
if(empty($email)){
    $msg[] = '<span style="color:red">Email address required.</span>';
    $msg['error'] = true;
}
```